# Possible workaround for having color and texture with Three.js CanvasRenderer?

Tags: three.js

I am using `CanvasRenderer` to render numerous `Sprite` objects.  I am mapping a texture (PNG image) to the `Sprites`.  I'd like to be able to change the color of the texture programmatically.

With the `WebGLRenderer`, I can use `ParticleSystem` and `ParticleSystemMaterial` to achieve this.  Here's a live demo of setting color to this texture (http://wxalert.info/private/dv/ball.png) with that technique: http://wxalert.info/private/dv/demo.html

But since `CanvasRenderer` does not support `ParticleSystem`, I am using `Sprites` instead with a `SpriteBasicMaterial`.  Here's a live demo of this: http://wxalert.info/private/dv/demo2.html

I'd like to be able to set the color with `CanvasRenderer` just like with `WebGLRenderer`, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

One thought was perhaps to load the image to an HTML5 canvas element, apply the color there, and then load the canvas context from the material.  But any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Here's an example of kind of what I was thinking of doing if using the HTML5 canvas: http://wxalert.info/private/dv/html5canvas.html. Basically, I would do the color manipulation there and then just load the canvas from the material. But wasn't sure if there was a simpler or better way.

Comment: You suggestion will work of course. Are the transparent parts of your texture 100% transparent or partially transparent? Do you want the non-transparent parts to be tinted by the base color? Do you want the texture to act like a decal? Is the texture black and white only?

Comment: Better-yet, can you show a simple, live webgl example that you are trying to replicate with `CanvasRenderer`?

Comment: When I was using `WebGLRenderer`, I used `ParticleSystem` and `ParticleSystemMaterial`.  But since `CanvasRenderer` does not support this, I converted everything to `Sprite` and `SpriteMaterial`. But here is a live demo of what I was doing with `WebGLRenderer` and `ParticleSystem` before: http://wxalert.info/private/dv/demo.html, and the texture image: http://wxalert.info/private/dv/ball.png. And here's a demo of what I've been doing with `CanvasRenderer` -- http://wxalert.info/private/dv/demo2.html. I want to be able to dynamically set color to the transparent part of "ball.png".

Comment: You said "the color will 'shine through' the transparent portion of the texture". It seems you want the opaque portion to be colored. No? Do you want each ball a different color?

Comment: Yes, sorry, the opaque portion -- to achieve a similar effect as the `WebGLRenderer`. I'll update the question. And yes, the ability to do different colors for each ball would be preferred.

Comment: OK, well, that explains a thing or two... What you are doing is the best solution. You solved your own problem.